# How to get java.time.LocalDateTime object of upcoming specific time?

Tags: java

I have an Object of current java.time.LocalDateTime. Is there a simple way to get the LocalDateTime object for the upcoming specific time? Suppose the current date  and time is 17/10/2019 8.00pm. The upcoming date of next 5.00 am will be 18/10/2019. Suppose the current date and time is 17/10/2019 2.00 am, then the upcoming date of next 5.00 am will be 17/10/2019 itself.

How to achieve this in a simple way? Is there a specific method for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, that's pretty easy. You could compare the `LocalTime` of the "start" part to see whether or not you need to add a day, but it's probably just as easy to speculatively create a `LocalDateTime` on the same day with the target time, and then add a day to that if necessary:

```
public static LocalDateTime next(LocalDateTime start, LocalTime targetTime)
{
    LocalDateTime candidate = start.with(targetTime);
    return candidate.isBefore(start) ? candidate.plusDays(1) : candidate;
}
```

Note that that will return `start` if it's already *at* the right time. If you want to change it to return a "strictly later" value, just change the last line to:

```
return candidate.isAfter(start) ? candidate : candidate.plusDays(1);
```